# How to use PHP to fetch data from an existing query?

Tags: dom, mysqli

I'm using MySQLi queries to fetch data from certain timeframes from my database. Only, the amount of queries is drastically slowing down the website. Now I've heared it's possible you can use PHP code to fix this.

PROBLEM:
MySQLi queries:
`$data["name_of_data"] = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE();"`

`$data["name_of_data"] = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND CURDATE();`

`$data["name_of_data"] = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CRUDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE();"`

So... there's a way to use PHP code to use the 30 day query to fetch the data for the 14 day query. Anyone knows how? Or knows a website where it is described (I'm terrible at google searching :/ )

I'll keep you guys updated if I have found a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so the solution is simple.

Just loop through all the data.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $row['array_one'] = (int)$row['array_one'];
     if($row['array_two'] == value){
          //enter code here
     }
}
```

So, long story short, just use filters like $variable['array']

I myself discovered this the hard way (trial and error)